# Is my code sufficient to prevent MediaPlayer leakage?

Tags: android, media-player, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, activity-lifecycle

In my Activity I have the following:

```
private Set<MediaPlayer> mediaPlayers;

public void onSomeEventInMyActivity()
{
    // play sound
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.my_sound);
    mediaPlayers.add(mediaPlayer);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.release();
            mediaPlayers.remove(mp);
        }
    });
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    mediaPlayers = new HashSet<MediaPlayer>();
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    for (MediaPlayer mediaPlayer : mediaPlayers)
    {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

Is this code sufficient or will it lead to MediaPlayer leakage? Are my implementations of `onStop` and `onStart` necessary, or can I just rely on calling `release` in `onCompletion`?

I did my code this way because I assume `onStop()` could be called while a MediaPlayer is playing, so I need to call `release` because `onCompletion` won't be called yet. I'm just guessing that this is right, so correct me if I am wrong.

I also read that `onStop` is not called in low-memory situations - what to do then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `onStop()` routine is needed if the mediaPlayer is expected to stop when the activity becomes  invisible. Otherwise, the mediaPlayer goes on playing. On older OSs, Gingerbread and earlier, the activity can execute `onPause()` - say, when a phone call arrives - and, in extreme circumstances, be destroyed without ever executing `onStop()`. I don't know what would happen to a running mediaPlayer then. However, if there is a phone call coming in, it might be an idea to stop the mediaPlayer in `onPause()`!  Later OSs always pass through `onStop()` before destroying the Activity. Calling `mp.release()` on the mediaPlayer after stopping it, in either `onPause()` or `onStop()`, is correct.

It's also desirable to remove the reference to the player held in `mediaPlayers`, which doesn't happen in onStop() above. Something like:

```
    @Override public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.stop();   // It's always safe to call stop()
        mp.release();  // release resources internal to the MediaPlayer
        mediaPlayers.remove(mp); // remove reference to MediaPlayer to allow GC
    }
```

and then

```
@Override public void onPause() {
     for (Object mediaPlayer : mediaPlayers.toArray()) {
          onCompletion((MediaPlayer) mediaPlayer); // stop, release, and free for GC, each mp.
     } 
     super.onPause();
}
```

(I originally had `for (Object mediaPlayer : mediaPlayers) {}` in the above code but omfeddf345mnof32nisd45fgoq2t pointed out that I would be modifying a set while iterating over it. Thanks for the correction!)

Comment: So I guess `onPause` is the safest option, and code you've posted above should be sufficient for all OSes, both new and old? Just want to confirm that there's nothing additional I need to do other than the code you've posted above...

Comment: I don't think there's anything extra needed, that's how I'd program it. If your app is rotation-enabled, then your activity will be destroyed, which includes executing `onPause`, on a rotation event, then recreated, and you'd have to watch for that in `onPause` and not call `onCompletion` in that case if you want to keep the audio going. Simplest to forbid rotation! Good Luck!

Comment: Another small question... where is the best place to create the HashSet of MediaPlayer objects? `onCreate`, `onStart`, `onResume`? I only need to do it once, right? So might as well do it in `onCreate`...?

Comment: Well, that depends quite what you want to do with them... For example, what you want to happen to them if the phone is put to sleep while playing and woken up again. I suggest you ask another question so you can set it out in detail.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed your code will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` in `onPause`, because you are removing `MediaPlayers` from the set at the same time that you are iterating over it. To fix this, I made it iterate over an array copy of the set instead e.g. `for (Object mediaPlayer : activeMediaPlayers.toArray()) { onCompletion((MediaPlayer) mediaPlayer); }` If you could update your answer with this (or another solution that you think is better), that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Only callback guaranted to be called  is onPause(), so you may leak this media player in some situations.  In case stopping player on activity pause is not acceptable you should use  service,   and watch for certain events ( like incoming phone call etc )